# Alternatives to JREBEL for IBM RAD

Tags: jrebel, redeploy, javarebel

I am looking for open source Alternatives to JREBEL which can be used in IBM RAD

I tried [Dynamic Code Evolution](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) VM with IBM Websphere and RAD . DCEVM does not recognize IBM jdk. Has anyone tried this and got a workaround for this? I believe this is due to the fact that the installer searches for jvm.dll in bin/client/jvm.dll and bin/server/jvm.dll folder and ibm jdk has it in jdk\jre\bin\j9vm and jdk\jre\bin\classic . Not sure if it is  the only issue.

But just wanted to know if someone has tried it and solved this problem .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there is no direct alternative to JRebel, both open-source and commercial. DCEVM is only capable of improved code-reloading (compared to HotSwap) and has no any framework or application server awareness. Also as you already found out it only works with SUN JVM. BTW, you should be able to use Websphere with SUN JVM too if what DCEVM provides is enough for you.

Javeleon is another product that does code reloading but it is specializing on NetBeans platform and cannot help with reloading framework and application server specific bits such as Spring/JPA/EJB/Log4j and many other specific configurations and code changes. It has free version, but not open source.

PS. I am one of JRebel developers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my JEE projects (DCEVM+hotswapagent could not handle that my projects were being deployed as symlinks).

The JDK already provides a way to do hotswapping for 'in-body' code changes using the JDI (Java Debug Interface). This is good enough for me, I just want to spare myself a full redeploy when I do changes in the body of the methods.

I wrote a basic java hotswapper with an executable jar:

https://github.com/tencnivel/java-basic-hotswapper